# Inconsistent System.IO.FileLoadException from CefSharp.Cef.GetGlobalCookieManager

Tags: c#, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I am getting the below error in a CefSharp WinForms application. This error happens very sporadically and **is not consistent**. Unfortunately at this time we are unable to replicate it, but it has been reported numerous times.

`System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.Runtime.dll' or one of its dependencies. Not enough memory resources are available to process this command. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070008) at CefSharp.Cef.GetGlobalCookieManager(ICompletionCallback callback)`

At first glance, I am skeptical that we are missing any required dependencies in the executing folder. Even though we are getting the FileLoadException, the memory HRESULT and the inconsistency of this error make me think that there is something else going on here. I have seen other examples of this FileLoadException of the CefSharp.Core.dll, but none that reference "Not enough memory resources are available to process this command."

Does anyone have any tips for troubleshooting this error? Is it possible this is still an issue with missing dependencies if the error occurs very inconsistently?

Comment: What version are you using? Are you targeting x86/x64? What .Net version? If it works sometimes then a missing file is unlikely.

Comment: The application is targeting x86/x64, using CefSharp version 92, and .NET Framework 4.8. But yes, it does work most of the time.

Comment: Have you considered that the exception was correct and the process ran out of memory? For 32bit applications you need to make sure your applicaiton is `LargeAddressAware` see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#win32-out-of-memory